# Tier pricing in a pricing table

Tags: product, price, tierprice, product-prices

I'm looking to have a pricing table (on the frontpage) for one specific product, but 3 different (predefined) quantities.

Showing the product and having the correct add to cart links on the page was relatively easy:

```
$_productId = '498';
$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$_url       = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);
```

Getting the Qty 1 price including tax, currency and some formatting was easy as well:

```
$_price = Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice()));
```

This results in `<span class="price">€15,00</span>`

However, my goal is to have a pricing table like:

```
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│  Single   │ ValuePack │ FamilyPack│
├───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│   €15     │    €10    │    €7.50  │
├───────────┼───────────┼───────────┤
│  Qty 1    │   Qty 5   │   Qty 10  │ 
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Getting the Qty * X price wasn't hard either:

```
$_qty = 5; 
$_price = Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice($_qty)));
```

As expected, this results in `<span class="price">€10,00</span>`

However, even though I change $_qty, the output of the other 2 prices is always the same as the first.

Illustration:

`$_price_1 = Mage::helper('core .... $_product->getFinalPrice(1)));` results in `€15`
`$_price_2 = Mage::helper('core .... $_product->getFinalPrice(5)));` results in `€15` as well 
`$_price_3 = Mage::helper('core .... $_product->getFinalPrice(10));` results in `€15` as well

I'm assuming this has something to do with Magento caching the product price after the first lookup.

Anybody got a clue on how to create this table the correct way?

Comment: Maybe this is because you set $_qty = 5, but you use $_Qty (or is this a typo)

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff - just a (now corrected typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out getting the tier-pricing was not that hard either as this is available in an Array `$_product->getFormatedTierPrice()` (note the incorrect spelling!).

This array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [32000-2] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 50
            [website_id] => 4
            [all_groups] => 1
            [cust_group] => 32000
            [price] => 21.95
            [price_qty] => 2.0000
            [website_price] => 24.95
            [formated_price] => € 18,95
        )

    [32000-4] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 52
            [website_id] => 4
            [all_groups] => 1
            [cust_group] => 32000
            [price] => 23.95
            [price_qty] => 4.0000
            [website_price] => 23.95
            [formated_price] => € 17,95
        )

    [32000-10] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 56
            [website_id] => 4
            [all_groups] => 1
            [cust_group] => 3200024.95
            [price] => 22.95
            [price_qty] => 10.0000
            [website_price] => 22.95
            [formated_price] => € 16,95
        )

    [32000-25] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 57
            [website_id] => 4
            [all_groups] => 1
            [cust_group] => 32000
            [price] => 19.95
            [price_qty] => 25.0000
            [website_price] => 21.95
            [formated_price] => € 15,95
        )

    [32000-50] => Array
        (
            [price_id] => 58
            [website_id] => 4
            [all_groups] => 1
            [cust_group] => 32000
            [price] => 19.95
            [price_qty] => 50.0000
            [website_price] => 19.95
            [formated_price] => € 14,95
        )

)
```

I only require 2 items from this multidimensional array: [price_qty] and [formated_price].

So I ended up with the following code:

```
$_productId = '498';
$_product   = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productId);
$_single = Mage::helper('core')->currency(Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice())); // Just the single product price
$_prices = array_column($_product->getFormatedTierPrice(), 'formated_price', 'price_qty'); // Extract price_qty and formated_price from Array of formatted tier prices
```

And in my pricing table I now have:

```
<li class="price">
  <?php 
    $_qty = '10.0000'; 
    if (array_key_exists($_qty, $_prices)) { 
      echo $_prices[$_qty]; 
    } else { 
    echo $_single; 
    } 
  ?>
</li>
```

With `else { echo $_single;}` I ensure that if someone changed tier qty in the backend (tier qty's are currently hardcoded in my phtml) I at least output the single product price instead of no price at all.